# How to find time difference even if first time is more than time() with sql?

Tags: php, sql, timestamp

I'm working on a little advertisement system for my project. Is it possible to find the time difference if one time is more than the current time, using the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` function?

For example, a user buys 12 days ads, so I store the timestamp of

```
time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 12)
```

How can I get the difference between now and then, in case the advert has expired?

Comment: So basically you want to know how to get the difference between the timestamp of RIGHT NOW compared to the expiration of the ad?

Comment: @keeleon Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must get `time()` and check in in your query

```
$time = time();
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `time` > $time";
//execute query and show ads
```

also if you want to check in php

```
if($adstime > time() )
{
//show ads
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the following code you will get the number of days between the allotment and current date

```
$daysremaining = ceil(abs(strtotime($allotmenttill) - strtotime($currentdate)) / 86400);
```

if it returns 0 that means the allotment period is over and if negative means the time period has expired.

Comment: -1 , abs return a positive value, you just calculate days between 2 time.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current timestamp by using time() command and then calculate difference.

```
 if($timestamp > time()){
    //not expired
 }
 else{
    //expired
 }
```

It's a basic comparision and you don't need any special functions.